# Eigenvectors' corresponding eugenvalues in Python

Tags: python, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have a symmetric 3*3 matrix, A:

```
A = np.mat("1, 2, 1; 2, 5, 0; 1, 0, 5")
```

I have calculated the eigenvalues of A, which is 0, 6 and 5.
I have now been told that A has the following three eigenvectors, and I am asked to find the corresponding three eigenvalues. How do I do this in Python?

```
   v1=np.array([[-5],[2], [1]])
   v2=np.array([[0],[-1], [2]])
   v3=np.array([[1],[2], [1]])
```

Afterwards I have to show that the three eigenvectors are linearly independent, which I also don't know how to show in Python?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html

Comment: It's recommended to use numpy `ndarrays` rather than matrices as matrices are only included for backwards compability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the eigenvalue of a given eigenvector there is a well known formula (Rayleigh quotient):

[image: eigenvalue]

And to find if the eigenvectors are linearly independent, you can show that their determinant is different than zero:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [2, 5, 0], [1, 0, 5]])

v1 = np.array([[-5], [2], [1]])
v2 = np.array([[0], [-1], [2]])
v3 = np.array([[1], [2], [1]])

# eigenvalues
l1 = (v1.T@A@v1/(v1.T@v1))[0, 0]
l2 = (v2.T@A@v2/(v2.T@v2))[0, 0]
l3 = (v3.T@A@v3/(v3.T@v3))[0, 0]

# Are linearly independent?
tol = 1e-8
if np.abs(np.linalg.det(np.concatenate((v1, v2, v3), axis=1))) < tol:
    print('eigenvector are linearly dependent')
else:
    print('eigenvector are linearly independent')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you have tried but here is the [link](https://s-mat-pcs.oulu.fi/~mpa/matreng/eem4_1-7.htm) that describes theoretical aspect on this topic.

In terms of python code, you can try this

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig
from numpy.linalg import det

A = np.mat("1, 2, 1; 2, 5, 0; 1, 0, 5")
values, vector = eig(A)
det(vector)
```

Comment: I have done that, and that worked - that gave me the det(A) which is 0, and the eigenvalues: 0, 6 and 5.
However, my assignment now is to find the three eigenvalues corresponding to the three eigenvectors that I have been given (v1, v2, and v3 in my code)